# Python CGI accessing angular POST data. TypeError: must be str not bytes

Tags: python, angularjs, json

I have an extremely simple python script that I just can't get to accept the data being sent to it from angular. I have read a bunch of posts and tried the suggestions of adding `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoder'}` and I have tried using `JSON.stringify()` to convert the data into a json string but still I receive the same TypeError.

**Angular Controller**

```
.controller('ContactCtrl', function($http) {
  var vm= this;

  vm.success = false;
  vm.error = false;
  vm.msg = {};

  vm.submit = function(input) {
    console.log('submit fired', input);
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/cgi-bin/sendMail.py',
      data: JSON.stringify(input),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoder'}
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      if(data.success) {
        console.log('success', data);
        vm.success = true;
      }else{
        console.log('error');
        vm.error = true;
      }
    })
  };
})
```

**.py**

```
#!/home/gjordan904/public_html/modernage/ModernAge/bin/python

import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable(logdir='/home/gjordan904/public_html/modernage/cgi-bin')

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
email = form.getValue('email')
subject = form.getValue('subject')
message = form.getValue('message')

print("Content-type: text/html")
print()

print("""<html>
<body>
<h1>""")

print(email)

print("""</h1>
</body>
</html>""")
```

Comment: submit as FormData

Comment: @JahirulIslamBhuiyan Thanks, that got the data through but now I get an Attribute error on the next line, `email = form.getValue('email')` the error says, "traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of AttributeError object>"